# Not a Structure or Union

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Whenever I try to build this code

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "NetworkGUI.h"
#include "String.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_NetworkGUI_getNetworkNames(JNIEnv 
*env, jobject obj)
{
    char *networkNames[3];
    networkNames = {"TWC", "Comcast", "Spectrum"};
    jobjectArray names;

    names = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(3, env->FindClass("Java/lang/String"), env -> NewStringUTF(""));

    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        env -> SetObjectArrayElement(names, i, 
        NewStringUTF(networkNames[i]));
    }
    return (names);
}
```

I get

> request for member '*******' in something not a structure or union

for `NewObjectArray`, `NewStringUTF`, `FindClass`, and 'SetObjectArrayElement' in the lines where they are called. Here is my header file

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "jni.h"
/* Header for class NetworkGUI */

#ifndef _Included_NetworkGUI
#define _Included_NetworkGUI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     NetworkGUI
 * Method:    hostRun
 * Signature: (I)I
 */

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_NetworkGUI_getNetworkNames
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

What exactly is causing this?

Comment: This is going to cause problems:  `env->FindClass("String")`.  "String" is not a fully-qualified class name.

Comment: My code had "Java/lang/String" in it, I just put String while I was copying it over

Comment: `"Java/lang/String"` isn't [the proper type signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276) either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give us a minimal example that we could try nor the line where the error occurs, but my guess is that this

```
(jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(...)
```

does something different than you thought. In C, postfix operators such as `->` and `(...)` have higher lexical priority than cast. You might want to add some parenthesis to make it clear what you mean.

Comment: I updated it to give a concrete example to test. I also added the header file for reference